# what is the maximum value for virtual memory limit in iis version 10 and windows server 2016

Tags: windows, iis

For the iis supplied with windows 10 and windows server 2016 with a user defined application pool.

1. What is the maximum value allowed for Virtual Memory Limit and Private Memory Limit (other than 0 for infinite)?
2. What is the maximum value allowed for Request Limit (other than 0 for infinite)?

Comment: are you looking for the next highest value below unlimited?

Comment: The literal maximum is the maximum of `unit`, but in reality that's meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

1. The max values for Virtual Memory Limit and Private Memory Limit are the max values for an unsigned 32 Bit integer (4,294,967,295)
2. The max value for Request Limit is also `uint` or 4,294,967,295

These are the max values enforced by the schema for IIS XML configuration files, whether they make sense technically is a different question.